# Gradle - SpringBoot with Java 7

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a SpringBoot application running just fine with Java 8. I was just told that the server we will deploy the application can only run Java 7 or lower. It's still a small application but I'm trying to just change the `build.gradle` to make it work. I am stuck with the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.16.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.menighin'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
//  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session-core')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
//  testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

I just lowered the `springBootVersion` and set the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to `1.7`. Any ideas what else I need to change to which versions? [SpringBoot documentation on 1.5.16](http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn) seems to be broken :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's going to fly anyway. That class/JAR is compiled for JDK `1.8`. hence the `UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

In any case, that version is a `SNAPSHOT`. I would recommend to use `1.5.15 GA` (you see, only a minor version lower ;p )...and that's guaranteed to run against Java `1.7` – unless whoever wrote the documentation was doing something wrong. Refer to [System Requirements](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.15.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements).

Comment: It did work! Thanks!
Now I only have to fix a lot of things in my code... Man, I hate old stuff :/